# Recursion for assigning jobs

Tags: php, cakephp, loops, recursion, logic

This is a specific question, so I'll quickly explain the background first. I'm working on software that assigns employees to a specific "job" for the day. In order for them to work the job, they must be trained, so the system knows what each employee has and hasn't been trained on.

Right now what I'm doing is something like:

```
foreach ($jobs as $job){
   foreach($employees as $emp){
       if (job doesn't have employee && employee isn't assigned to job && employee has been trained on job){
          assign them;
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

This works somewhat, however there is an issue. Consider the following simplified example.

There are 2 jobs: "Checkout" and "Customer Service"

There are 2 employees: "Bill" and "Lucy". Bill knows both jobs, Lucy only knows Checkout.

When the loop runs through, it will first look for someone to work Checkout. It will first look at Bill, see he can work it, and assign him. It will them move on to look for Customer Service. It skips over bill because he is already assigned, and checks Lucy, but she can't work it! This causes an unnecessary training.

I could easily code it so that if it runs through all the employees and doesn't find anyone, it goes through like this:

```
//We didn't find anyone, let's look for a potential swap
foreach($employees as $emp){
   if (emp has been trained on job && emp is already assigned something else){
      //Find someone else to work their assigned job, so they can work this one
      foreach($employees as $emp2){
         if ($emp != $emp2 && emp2 can work emp's job && emp2 isn't already assigned anything){
            swap the two;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Fairly simple. But that only works for a swap that deals with 2 employees. What if the swap was so complicated that it involved moving four people around? Ideally I'd like to come up with a recursive solution that I can set a value $maxDepth = 5 or something.

If it can't find someone immediately, it goes to a depth of 2, looking for the two person swap I described above. If it still can't, it goes to depth 3 looking for a three person swap, etc.

Comment: This is a variation of what's known as the Knapsack Problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. The wiki page contains pseudo solutions, maybe one can help you.

Comment: As MaX said, this problem is NP-Complete... Your greedy algorithm can get you into trouble. You may want to consider a dynamic programming solution, which will effectively look at all subsets of possible assignments but in a smart way with memoization. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming

Comment: I will definitely investigate those resources, thank you very much. Swiecki, just for curiosity's sake, what do you mean by my algorithm being greedy?

Comment: By greedy algorithm, I mean an algorithm that does the best possible thing at every step, but is incapable of making short-term sacrifices for a better overall result. Example: Your algorithm always assigns a job to the first free employee, but is incapable of knowing that it should not pick Bill for job 1 because it will need him for job 2 in the optimal solution.

Comment: Can't see why everyone's thinking of the knapsack problem. Looks like an assignment problem to me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. Can be solved using the Hungarian algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm in O(n^3) or O(n^4). (Wikipedia's explanation isn't very good, hopefully you can find a better one by googling.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, this is a [Bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) in which you want the maximum number of matches, which can be reduced to a network flow problem and solved with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. This is well explained [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf).

Comment: This is nearly perfect! My only question is if you've heard of a way to make it so not all edges are equal. I.e. one edge is more ideal than another edge, but the lesser is still an option if need be.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm which is based on Max Flow Min Cost. The hungarian algorithm is also a very good solution too. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for finding a solution! :D
I wouldn't have seen how Ford-Fulkerson would work with the weights
as the hungarian algorithm would be first to come to mind in this case.

Comment: This is correct. The answer I submitted below is incorrect and I have marked it for deletion.

Comment: Upvoted, but you need to [actually include the information in your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) rather than just provide a link. This protects against linkrot.